# How to install PostgreSQL 9.5 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, compiling, postgresql

I want to install PostgreSQL 9.5. But the available version is 9.6.

I only need 9.5 to build `wal2json` against it and test it (requirement because of AWS version).

Comment: How exactly did you determine the PostgreSQL version after installation of `postgresql-9.6`? Is it possible that you have another installation of PostgreSQL set up on your system in a way that takes precedence over the former?

Comment: Doh! You are right. I had few docker containers running and one was at 5432.
However, still, I need 9.5 and the package available is 9.6. I have changed the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Note for whoever compiles against PostgreSQL: Make sure you have the right `postgresql-dev-<version>` package installed, and not `postgresql-dev-all`. Also check `pg_config` output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last supported release that includes postgresql-9.5 in its default repositories is Ubuntu 16.04. Manually download the following two files from the official Ubuntu website:

- [postgresql-client-9.5_9.5.12-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/postgresql-client-9.5/download)
- [postgresql-9.5_9.5.12-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/postgresql-9.5/download)

The two .deb files have been updated to  postgresql-client-9.5_9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb and postgresql-9.5_9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb.

Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the two .deb files that you downloaded. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install libedit2 libpq5 libssl1.0.0 postgresql-client-common zlib1g libgssapi-krb5-2 libldap-2.4-2 libpam0g libxml2 postgresql-common locales ssl-cert tzdata sysstat 
sudo apt install ./postgresql-client-9.5_9.5.12-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb ./postgresql-9.5_9.5.12-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb
```

Current versions of postgresql-all:

```
Ubuntu postgresql-all   
18.04   10     
19.10   11     
20.04   12  
20.10   12     
21.04   13   
21.10   13  
22.04   13
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me